# Drop down menu disarray in ie8

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, internet-explorer-8

This is my code for a menu with drop-downs. It's ok in all browsers but ie8. I can't understand the problem. I'll be glad to know your opinions.

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav_wrapper">
  <li id="menu_3">
    <a href="#"> A </a>
    <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_3" style="display: none">
      <li id="menu_5"><a href="main.php?pages=5"> 1 </a></li>
      <li id="menu_6"><a href="main.php?pages=6"> 2 </a></li>
      <li id="menu_7"><a href="main.php?pages=7"> 3 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li id="menu_18"><a href="main.php?pages=18"> B </a></li>

  <li id="menu_19">
    <a href="#"> C </a>
    <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_19" style="display: none">
      <li id="menu_20"><a href="main.php?pages=20"> 1 </a></li>
      <li id="menu_21"><a href="main.php?pages=21"> 2 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and this is the Stylesheet. I've removed some unnecessary styles like background and border,...

```
.nav_wrapper {
left: 0px;
margin-top: 7px;
padding: 0px;
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
Z-index:10;}

#nav > li { 
display: inline;
float: right;
position: relative;}

li { 
font-family: "tahoma";
font-size: 10pt;
list-style: none outside none;
}

li a {
float: right;
padding: 18px 15px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.sub_menu {
float: right;
line-height: normal;
margin-left: -60px;
margin-top: 55px;
padding: 0px;
position: fixed;
width: 202px;
}

.sub_menu li {
display: inline-block;
text-align: right;
 }

.sub_menu li a {
direction: rtl;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 1;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
width: 192px;
 }
```

The problem is that in ie8 the main menu apears cascade from right to left. And the sub menus are not in right place under the main menu items.

Comment: Could you tell us what the problem is?

Comment: sorry, I explained it in question. the problem is that in ie8 the main menu apears cascade from right to left. and the sub menus are not in right place under the main menu items.

Comment: From a quick scan I can see that on sub-menu you're using position fixed and float right. This won't work. You probably want to use position absolute and no float.

Comment: I agree to Billy Moat... Additionally, just for the safer side need to add z-index to get it above the content...

Comment: yes, it's weird but works better in ie8 :p this is how it looks in ie8: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/402/menuoq.png/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/GMajE/

Check this out. What you need to do is remove float:right from the following class:

```
#nav > li { 
display: inline;
float: right;
position: relative;}
```

And you need to change the .nav_wrapper class to this :

```
.nav_wrapper {
left: 0px;
margin-top: 7px;
padding: 0px;
right: 0px;
Z-index:10;
float:right;}
```

And regarding the submenu. You should put position:relative in the main navigation's li and put position:absolute and then put left/right/top/bottom accordingly in the submenu. I have not setup the submenu in the fiddle just so you know.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it didnt solve it. main menu still is not inline, it's cascade yet

Comment: If you could provide the link for the page itself then it'd be helpful as you can see in the fiddle that the menu items are inline so its not this css that is creating an issue i am guessing. Just upload to a test site if you cannot provide the real link.